# Any way to dismiss a cronjob in Magento

Tags: mysql, magento, cron

Given: extension that has a properly configured cronjob (let's say, every 5 minutes) in Config.xml. Also, the system cron is set to run Magento's cron.sh. The cronjob has to run a couple of times after the extension installed, and when it has no more data to process then it becomes obsolete.

Problem: the job isn't needed after it had processed all the data. However, its setup in Config.xml causes it to run every 5 minutes forever, just to check that there is no more data and die.

Question: is there any proper way (maybe with the cron_schedule table...) to 'dismiss' the cronjob programmatically from its own PHP when it sees that there is no more data? Or any other way?
The cron is used since the extension installation process shouldn't be interrupted. Maybe it's possible to schedule some PHP code in some other way than cron (but within Magento)? Thought about threading but since there is no guarantee that this feature will be built in, this doesn't seem to be the option....

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I don't think Magento has any built-in mechanism for what you want. There is, however, a very popular extension Aoe_Scheduler (https://github.com/AOEpeople/Aoe_Scheduler), which allows to set the status of a task to DISABLED, so that it wouldn't run anymore. You could put a dependency on that extension in yours, and use the functionality provided by the module, or you could implement it by yourself... I hope it helps.

Comment: @JavierC.H.Thanks, but I've already found 2 possible solutions: 1) it seems to be possible to create/remove crontabs via core_config_data table without config.xml; 2) remove the crontab node from config.xml after all data is processed + clean the cache + remove all pending tasks. I've managed to implement the 2nd, and it works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, I found 2 possible solutions: 1) it seems to be possible to create/remove crontabs via core_config_data table without config.xml; 2) remove the crontab node from config.xml after all data is processed + clean the cache + remove all pending tasks. I've managed to implement the 2nd, and it works (I know that the 1st approach is much better, but I just had no time to dig it out).

The 2nd looks like:

```
if ($more_data) {
    // processing...
} else { // Dismissing the cron
    $config_xml_path = Mage::getModuleDir('etc', 'the_extension') . '/config.xml';
    $config_xml = simplexml_load_file($config_xml_path) or die("Error: Cannot create object");
    if (isset($config_xml) && isset($config_xml->crontab)) {
        unset($config_xml->crontab);
        $config_xml->asXML($config_xml_path);
    }
    // Cleaning
    Mage::app()->cleanCache();
    $schedule = Mage::getModel('cron/schedule');
    $sch_col = $schedule->getCollection()
        ->addFilter('job_code', 'the_extension_cronFunc')
        ->addFilter('status', 'pending');
    foreach ($sch_col as $s) {
        $s->delete();
    }
}
```

Comment: The first approach is interesting, thanks. Regarding the second one, well, I thought about it but I discarded it as you are changing the source code, and can't relay on that because some people would add the extension to their own repository, so the next deployment would revert the changes of the xml... anyway, it might be useful for other situations.